# Appengine: How to debug too many datastore writes?

Tags: google-app-engine, debugging, google-cloud-datastore

I have a little web shop hosted on AppEngine. It has ~100 products. Apart from orders (1/month) and registrations (1/month), I am not writing to the datastore. 
I have a session included (http://gaeutilities.appspot.com/cookiesession) and some indexes for sorting.

Analytics tells me it was 1,315 page views in the last 30 days. That is ~44 per day causing 50,000 write operations (=1136/request)?

I can't really believe that. Any ideas how to debug this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend taking a look at [AppStats](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats), which will give you a breakdown of all your RPC calls.  It's really very handy for exactly this kind of scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The logs helped (oh wonder!). It always fails by using the session:

```
[..]
File "/base/data/home/apps/[..]/12.376983336014703566/appengine_utilities/sessions.py", line 87, in put
    db.put(self)
[..]
OverQuotaError: The API call datastore_v3.Put() required more quota than is available.
```